# Reputation chart: columns are white in Chrome

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed

Anyone else see this? Is this just me or is it Chrome? The bars on the lower reputation chart show in white when Chrome is set to 100% zoom. in IE8 it looks fine. The screenshot shows IE at the top and Chrome at the bottom.

[image]

When I zoom out, the bars get faintly green

at 90%

[image]

The more I zoom in, the more bars become green. Following three screenshots are at 110%, 125% and 150% resolution.

[image]

[image]

Can anyone else repro this? I see this on all sites I have an account with.

Running Chrome 29.0.1547.57 m on Win 7 Enterprise, SP1